# Назначение указателю на не константу, ссылки на константу

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки, константа

Почему следующее можно сделать? И что тут происходит?:

```
const int& a = 10;
int* b;

*b = a;
```

Comment: здесь происходит запись по случайному адресу памяти (b не инициализированна). Поэтому коротко - UB. И кстати компилятор предупреждает.

Comment: А, понятно. Спасибо! (UB - это неопределенное поведение? (Unexpected Behaviour))

Comment: Да, UB = неопределенное поведение. Только "undefined", а не "unexpected".

Comment: Здесь вместо `const int& a = 10;` с тем же успехом могло быть `int a = 10;`. Или вместо `*b = a;` можно было сразу сделать `*b = 10;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом фрагменте кода

```
const int& a = 10;
int* b;

*b = a;
```

нет

> Назначение указателю на не константу, ссылки на константу

В этом фрагменте кода вы пытаетесь записать в память по неопределенному адресу (так как указатель, если имеет автоматическую память, не инициализирован, или если имеет статическую память, то инициализирован null-константой) значение 10, на которое ссылается ссылка `a`.  То есть фрагмент кода имеет неопределенное поведение.

Скорей всего вы имели в виду следующий фрагмент кода.

```
const int& a = 10;
int *b = &a;
```

В этом фрагменте кода имеет место попытка инициализировать не константный указатель (то есть указатель на не константный объект) адресом константного объекта, на который ссылается ссылка `a`.

Данный код также считается ill-formed, то есть не удовлетворяющий стандарту. Иначе вы могли бы изменить константный объект через этот не константный указатель.

Правильно было бы записать

```
const int& a = 10;
const int *b = &a;
```

То есть и ссылка константная, и указатель указывает на константный объект.

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int& a = 10;
    const int *b = &a;

    std::cout << "*b = " << *b << '\n';
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
*b = 10
```

И ссылка, и указатель - оба ссылаются на константный объект.

Рассмотрите другой аналогичный код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int i = 10;

    const int &a = i;

    int *b;

    b = &i;
//  b = &a;

    std::cout << "&a == &i is " << ( &a == &i ) 
              << ", &a == b is " << ( &a == b )
              << '\n';
}
```

В этой программе вы можете записать

```
b = &i;
```

так как и указатель и объект, на который будет ссылаться указатель, оба являются не константными.

Но вы не можете написать (в программе данное предложение закомментировано)

```
b = &a;
```

так как в данном случае в правой части имеется константная ссылка, то есть считается, что ссылка ссылается на константный объект, а в левой части расположен не константный указатель.

Тем не менее адреса объектов на которые ссылается ссылка и указатель, совпадают, так как они ссылаются на один и тот же объект.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему `int *b = &a;` вдруг "также имеет неопределенное поведение". Такой вариант сразу однозначно ошибочен (ill-formed) . И никакого неопределенного поведения не надо.

Comment: @AnT Хорошее замечание. Я подправил текст.

Answer (score 3):

Подозреваю, что вас интересовало иное - что-то вроде

```
const int& a = 10;
int* b = a;
```

Т.е. вы хотели получить через указатель доступ к константному значению/переменной и изменять его. Если бы такое было возможно, то, конечно, это было бы нарушением системы безопасности, константности - словом, поводом спросить - почему же такое возможно?

Но дело в том, что ссылка - это абсолютный синоним того, на что она ссылается. И она не может ссылаться на что-то иное - то, на что она ссылается, определяется при создании ссылки, и присвоение ссылке чего-либо иного оказывается присвоением значения - сама ссылка как указатель на что-то не меняется.

Вы можете написать

```
const int& a = 10;
const int * b = &a;
```

Но не можете

```
const int& a = 10;
int * b = &a;
```

Если это не то, что вас интересовало - тогда извините, но совершенно непонятно, к чему же тогда относится ваш вопрос "*почему это возможно*".

Comment: Да меня интересовало именно это. Название вопроса сформулировано неправильно ввиду того, что я не до конца понимал что же тут происходит. Спасибо